# What is the DTM in the following tablebase position?

Tags: computer-chess

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[fen "8/8/6k1/8/1N3R2/1P6/K1P5/4q3 b - - 0 1"]
```

or WHITE King on a2 Rook on f4 Knight on b4 pawns on b3 c2.BLACK King on g6 Queen on e1 BLACK to move. I know from other sources this position is winning for White, but what is the DTM and the relative line? Lomonosov is not working in my country.

Answer (score 1):

Check the following link

https://syzygy-tables.info/?fen=3q4/5P1K/6P1/2R3N1/8/1k6/8/8_b_-_-_0_1

hope This is Helpful